# Tooltip with click button to close -Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, tooltip, close-button

I want to display a tooltip with a close button on the page with instruction.when the page load tooltip should be there with close button so after reading instruction person can close the tooltip.currently with this code I manage to load tooltip but I would like to add a close button like the popup to close the tooltip. How I can add this?

```
 var tooltip = L.tooltip({
    direction: 'center',
    permanent: true,
    interactive: true,
    noWrap: true,
    opacity: 0.9
    });
    tooltip.setContent( "instructions" );
    tooltip.setLatLng(new L.LatLng(23.951,149.861));
    tooltip.addTo(map);
```

Comment: So... why not use popups instead?

Comment: yes, I end up using popup instead of Tooltip. I added the popup and I want it to close only after clicking the close button. it should not close when clicking on popup or outside popup.how can I achieve this? any idea?                                                                               ``` var popup = L.popup({
  closeButton: true,
  autoClose: true,
  closePopupOnClick :false
})
.setLatLng([20.951,149.861])
.setContent("intro")
.openOn(map);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP asked in the comments, how to disable closeing when clicking on map or popup:

You can use the option `closeOnClick: false` [Doc](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#popup):

```
var popup = L.popup({closeOnClick: false, closeButton: true, autoClose: true, closePopupOnClick :false })
.setLatLng([20.951,149.861]) 
.setContent("intro") 
.openOn(map);
```

Comment: thanks for the help. (closeOnClick : false)  has solved the problem.